# How to move robot by the number entered by user?

Tags: java

**I use drjava-stable-20120818-r5686 for coding**

```
    class Assignment2
    {
     public static void main(String[] args)
         {
      World barney=new World(20,20);
      Robot bob=new Robot();
      barney.addBeeper(6,4);
      barney.add(bob,4,4,"north");
      System.out.println("1. Turn left from current direction.");
     System.out.println("2. Turn right from current direction.");
     System.out.print("Enter Choice: ");
     int choice=Console.readInt();

     if(choice==1)
     {
     bob.turnLeft();
     }
     else
     {
     bob.turnLeft();
     bob.turnLeft();
     bob.turnLeft();
     }

     System.out.println("1. Move Forward Once.");
     System.out.println("2. Move Forward Twice.");
     System.out.println("3. Move Forward X Times.");
     System.out.println("Enter Choice: ");
     int choice2=Console.readInt();
     if(choice2==1)
     {
       bob.move();
     }
     if(choice2==2)
     {
        bob.move();
         bob.move();
     }
     else
     {
       System.out.println("Enter X: "); //dont know what to do next :(
    }
    [enter image description here][1]`
```

**Our teacher said to use loop(while) to do it, but I'm not really sure how
**

Comment: Maybe ask your teacher ?

Comment: Getting the answer here will not help you. Ask to your teacher or follow some tutorial to understand basics language. Then you will be able to solve this.

Comment: Or your fellow students (you probably figured that out already, this is just in case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like :

```
System.out.println("Enter X: ");
int x =Console.readInt();
while(x>0) {
         bob.move();
         x--;
         }
```

Comment: For this kind of question, I would suggest you to explain this code. In general this would not be needed for a simple code but you are answering to a new dev so he might not understand or simply copy past this code.

Comment: thanks @Khalil you made me look stupid :))

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. i'll consider it next time.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Oracle documentation for [While Loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html), the part about Syntax as mentioned below:

> while (expression) {
>        statement(s)
>   }

Using this, the following piece of code should solve your problem ...

```
int X=Console.readInt();
while(X-->0){ bob.move();}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to read [answer], especially the part about links in an answer.

Comment: I read it and this is how far I could get with the explanation ... Am I still missing something ?

Comment: That's better :) you could always explain briefly what is an expression an a statement but you will quickly end up writting a tutorial on Java ;)